# Casting to Func<T1,T2> at runtime with known T1 and T2

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a dictionary with the following definition

`Dictionary<string, object>` where the objects are of type `Func<T1, T2>`

The dictionary stores a variety of functions as objects with varying `T1` and `T2`. At runtime depending on the param passed I need to typecast the object to `Func<T1, T2>` but am unable to do so. I know the types at runtime of `T1` and `T2` but have not found a way to get this working.

Any ideas on how to get this up and running?

Comment: do you have any code?

Comment: Have you got a snippet of code you can show us how you are trying to typecast the object to Func?

Comment: Are you aware of the MakeGenericType-method: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx?

Comment: Make that a `Dictionary<string, MulticastDelegate>` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

In the end you have a `Delegate` (all the `Func<,>` and the other delegates are `Delegate`), so use it like a `Delegate` through reflection...

```
Delegate del = (Delegate)obj; // the object contained in the dictionary
object par = ... // your parameter
object result = del.DynamicInvoke(par);
```

Clearly `par1` must be of the "right" type. Note that your dictionary could directly have as the `TValue` the `Delegate` type.

```
Dictionary<string, Delegate> MyDictionary
```

Comment: And what if he´s building some (weird) kind of expression-tree that expects a Func? No use for delegate in this case.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If he is building an Expression then he can probably pass directly the Delegate... Some more code is needed, but the tags are `generics` and `reflection`, not `expressions`

Comment: I initially had a Dictionary<string, Delegate> but am trying to move from away from DynamicInvoke() to Invoke() for performance reasons. I am trying to build a linq expression that accesses all the class properties (including nested ones)

Comment: @user1542794 Even if you want to build expression trees, given a `Delegate del`, you can `Expression.Call(Expression.Constant(del.Target), del.Method, parameter1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you know that all of your delegates are instances of some `Func<T1, T2>`, you can query `T1` and `T2` by using `del.GetType().GetGenericTypeArguments()` when `del` is your delegate.

However, since the compiler does not know the contents of your dictionary, you cannot expect the compiler to know T1 or T2 at compile-time, so I don't know what you want to do with `T1` and `T2` but most of the things that I can think of will require some amount of reflection.

Thus, except there is a very good reason not to do so, I would also recommend to use `DynamicInvoke` like proposed by xanatos.

Comment: Am trying to move from away from DynamicInvoke() to Invoke() for performance reasons.

Comment: @user1542794 In that case some more code to be shown would be required to make a recommendation. How do you want to process your func delegates?